# How can I prevent programs closed by last session's shutdown to start again once I start a new session in Linux?

Tags: linux

Everytime I start a new session in my linux machine some programs closed by my last session's shutdown show up, and I have to close them up. It's starting to bother me. How can I prevent them to start again once I start a new session in Linux?

Sorry for my bad england.

Comment: What is your desktop environment? Can you provide examples of such programs? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.